# downgrade c++ compiler specefications

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I want to build a project that was originally built with `vs2010`, but I'm using `vs2015`(firebird SGBD). The problem is that I have lot of error messages due to the new features in `vs2015`, like i.e. `snprintf define`.

Since my c++ skills are not that great, I am asking the following questions:

- Is it possible to use `vs 2015` and sort of **downgrade** c++ compiler and linker to earlier specifications ?
- Is it possible to do the same thing but with `vs online` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Visual Studio, please right click the project and select Properties.  Change the Platform Toolset to be v100. (Be note that, VS2010 needs to be installed on the machine as well)

[image]

For build in VSO, please use **/p:PlatformToolset=v100** argument to use Visual C++ 2010 tools and libraries to build your application. 
[image]